# Could HttpUtility.UrlEncode() prevent Open Redirect attack?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, urlencode

I am checking a ASP.net MVC project for the security issues.

I found some code like the following, I am wondering is `UrlEncode()` preventing open redirect issue?

```
public ActionResult Redirect(string url)
{
   return Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url));
}
```

Comment: No, it will just encode it (replace illegal characters etc). Is you url to a page within your site or to an external url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

**Open Redirection** is basically allowing an attacker to redirect a victim to an unsafe/malicious page because of a missing URL verification.

Encoding the Url won't help.

To be able to prevent it you can see my answer on this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051915/7827699